# Under what conditions would humans host earth to alien refugees?

Tags: society, planets, science-fiction, culture

I'm trying to come up with two scenarios for my story that takes place in a distant future where a fleet of starships with millions of unarmed humanoid aliens landed on Earth and claimed that their home planet was destroyed by an asteroid , the aliens then insisted on staying with us because according to them Earth was the only habitable planet they could find after exploring the galaxy for over a thousand years. Both scenarios are the same except that the aliens look completely different.

The aliens in the first scenario have familiar customs and look remarkably similar to humans.
[image]

The aliens in the second scenario do not resemble humans and have customs that may seems revolting.

[image]

Realistically what actions will world leaders take to solve this problem?

And what would be the most realistic outcome in both scenarios?

Comment: "How would the world react to X" is quite broad, opinion-prone question. Could you edit the question to make it more focused?

Comment: If they've been wandering the galaxy for "over a thousand years", then they don't really seem to *need* a planet to settle upon. Frederick Pohl's *Homegoing* (1989) suggested Mars as an affordable fixer-upper in our neighborhood. Clarke's *Jupiter Five* (1953) had the immigrants a distinct but equal and welcomed partner in Solar System society for millennia. You can have the human politics work out any way you need to for the story. Some will view it as a problem; others will see opportunity.

Comment: You should watch District 9 - it's a good movie in itself and not-so-low-key an allegory for racism. It takes a South African perspective as this is where all the events take place, but it does make an interesting argument about how we treat refugees and those in need of our help.

Answer (score 1):

## Refugees, endangered species, and pests

I'm not an attorney but I have a Masters in Public Administration so I'll take a stab at this from a US perspective. There's massive prestige in being the country that makes first contact with an alien species. Realistically, Congress would probably have a special session to pass a law reacting to the aliens' request. Broadly, I see three ways of treating the aliens based on current law: refugees, endangered species, or pests. These three categories are based on existing law. I don't think these laws would actually be applied, but they give an overview of three very different approaches that Congress and the president could choose to follow.

**1. Refugees**

If the government decides to treat the people as humans, they could apply for refugee status. That would give the aliens a process (described [here](https://www.state.gov/refugee-admissions/)) to ask for permission to live here. The aliens could theoretically be allowed to settle wherever they wanted in the United States. I don't think this option is likely because there are just so many unknowns in how aliens and humans will interact.

**2. Endangered species**

If the creatures aren't treated as humans, they could be regarded as an endangered species. This would require the president and the administration to designate the species under the auspices of the Endangered Species Act (or for Congress to create a similar category for aliens). Endangered species can be kept in captivity in approved facilities, so this approach would let the government keep the aliens isolated in research facilities and separated from the general public. Here's the definition of an endangered species from the Act:

> [...] any species which is in danger of extinction throughout all or a
> significant portion of its range other than a species of the Class
> Insecta determined by the Secretary to constitute a pest whose
> protection under the provisions of this chapter would present an
> overwhelming and overriding risk to man.

**3. Pests**

That last part leads us to the third possibility: aliens as pests. The [Outer Space Treaty](https://2009-2017.state.gov/t/isn/5181.htm) says that member nations must take steps to prevent "adverse changes in the environment of the Earth resulting from the introduction of extraterrestrial matter and, where necessary, shall adopt appropriate measures for this purpose." If an alien species is regarded as threatening "adverse changes," Congress is authorized to enforce this treaty provision through law. That means that the government could destroy the aliens if so desired.